# Add allHTTPHeaderFields to URLRequest in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to add the bearer token to the URLrequest but unfortunately the request is nil, I don't know if I'm doing it in the correct way but for the moment it doesn't work.
My intention is to add either the user token or the anonymous token, it depends of a couple of things:

- If I have stored the user token in the keychain(SessionProvider) and the refresh token related to this user token is not expired then add to the request the user token
- If I have stored the user token in the keychain(SessionProvider) but the refresh token related to this user token is expired then add to the request the anonymous token
- If I don't have stored the user token in the keychain(SessionProvider) then add to the request the anonymous token

These are the 3 possibilities that I like to include in order to fill the URLrequest, but when I

> print("request (request.allHTTPHeaderFields)")

the result in console is

> request Optional([:])

What can I do to obtain the desired result?

```js
 public static var fake: Resource<[User]> = Resource(request: { (url) -> URLRequest in
        var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)!
        components.path = "/dev/fake-users"
        var request = URLRequest(url: components.url!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        if let token = SessionProvider().getUserToken(){
            SessionController().refreshToken(refreshToken: (SessionProvider().getUserToken()?.refreshToken)!, completion: { (error) in
                if let error = error{
                    if let anonymousToken = SessionProvider().getAnonymousToken(){
                        request.setValue("Bearer \(anonymousToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
                    }
                }else{
                   request.setValue("Bearer \(token.accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
                }
            })
        }
        else if let anonymousToken = SessionProvider().getAnonymousToken(){
            request.setValue("Bearer \(anonymousToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        }

        print("request \(request.allHTTPHeaderFields)")

        return request

    }) { (data) -> [User] in
        let unboxer = Unboxer(dictionary: data as! UnboxableDictionary)
        return try unboxer.unbox(key: "hits")
    }
```

Now the refresh token function

```js
 public static func refreshToken(refreshToken: String) -> Resource<String> {
        return Resource(request: { (url) -> URLRequest in

            var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)!
                components.path = "/v1/oauth/login"

            var request = URLRequest(url: components.url!)
                request.httpMethod = "POST"
                request.setValue("Basic \(Keys.basic)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
                request.setValue(SessionProvider().getInstanceToken(), forHTTPHeaderField: "x-bok-instance")

            var dictionary: [String: Any] = [:]
                dictionary["refreshToken"] = refreshToken
                dictionary["grantType"] = "refresh_token"

            request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictionary, options: [])
            return request
        }, dataParser: { data -> String in
            let unboxer = try Unboxer(data: data)
            return try Unboxer(data: data).unbox(key: "accessToken")
        })
    }
```

Comment: `refreshToken(refreshToken:)` is synchrone or asynchrone?

Comment: good question, how can I know it?

Comment: By giving its code?

Comment: I have just added the refresh token function